# Is there a required way of importing Laravel Log Class?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

A Laravel project is working locally well but fails when deployed to an EC2 instance using ElasticBeanstalk. The error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Log' not found in /var/app/current/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:35\nStack trace:\
```

The content of that line is `\Log::error($e);`

I've tried the following.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    {
        ...

        public function report(Exception $e)
        {
            ...

            {
                Log::error($e);
            }

        }
```

With this, I get a new error of:
`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.`

I also tried `use Log` but got an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Log' not found`.

Both these fails:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    {
        ...

        public function report(Exception $e)
        {
            ...

            {
                Log::error($e);
            }

        }
```

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    {
        ...

        public function report(Exception $e)
        {
            ...

            {
                \Log::error($e);
            }

        }
```

I didn't expect this error. My expectation was that Laravel already has this class.

Ps: I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: Are you certain this is Laravel and not Lumen? If it's Lumen, you need to uncomment `$app->withFacades();` in `bootstrap/app.php`.

Comment: @ceejayoz bootstrap/app.php doesn't have `$app->withFacades();`.

Comment: It's a laravel project

Comment: Have you run `composer install` on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes. Which generated a vendor folder

Comment: Is there a `'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,` line in your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326862/laravel-5-6-uncaught-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set-in-vendor indicates SELinux might be at play here, too.

Comment: Yes, it has `'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
\Log::info($e);
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: Where? Why? Please edit your question so as to include a bit of explanation.