# How to solve "Eloquent error: A facade root has not been set" when installing Homestead 8.0.0 on Mac

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm installing Laravel Homestead for the first time. The installation process seems to work fine, but I get an error when I try to connect to the virtual machine.

Up to this point all my Laravel development work has been done using PHP stack on my Mac.

I have followed the step-by-step instructions at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead

Installation works fine, and I can 
    vagrant ssh
and see the Homestead 8.0.0 installation working fine.

The problem comes when I try to view the site being served. I browse to 
    homestead.test
or 
    192.168.10.10

I expect to see the Laravel project displayed in the browser. Instead, I see an error message:

*Eloquent error: A facade root has not been set*

I know that the code is correct, because I can see it fine if I use
    php artisan serve
on my local machine.

I have reinstalled Vagrant and Homestead countless times now, and made sure VirtualBox is updated. What should I try next to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try downgrading Homestead to 7.2 version, like in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464835/757587

I had similar problem that got resolved by upgrading my VirtualBox 6. Are you absolutely sure you have VirtualBox on v6 (and everything else updated), and not something like v5 where you might have it up to date for that version only.

Comment: Thanks. I thought VirtualBox was up-to-date because that’s what it told me when I checked for updates within the application. Turns out that I needed to update to v6 manually by installing from the website.