# Laravel - A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan

I have a problem running tests in my laravel app.
My app is splitted into separated namespaces. Laravel App namespace is in app directory and it's App/ namespace. I have additional namespace in src directory.

My TestCase look like that:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Domain\User\User;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Domain\User\UserRepository;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Domain\User\ValueObject\ConfirmationCode;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Shared\ValueObjects\Email;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Shared\ValueObjects\Id;
use SmoothCode\Sample\Shared\ValueObjects\Password;
use Tests\CreatesApplication;


class UserDomainTest extends TestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected UserRepository $userRepository;

    public function testUserCreation() {
        $user = User::create(
            Id::generate(),
            'Jan',
            'Kowalski',
            new Email('test@test.com'),
            '123123123',
            new Password('Pass123!'),
            new \DateTimeImmutable(),
            ConfirmationCode::generate()
        );
//
//        $this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $user);
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }


}
```

After running vendor/bin/phpunit I'm getting following error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\UserDomainTest::testUserCreation
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.

/home/jakub/Development/Projects/streetboss-server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
/home/jakub/Development/Projects/streetboss-server/src/Sample/Shared/ValueObjects/Password.php:15
/home/jakub/Development/Projects/streetboss-server/tests/Unit/UserDomainTest.php:29
```

From that i know that the problem lies in src/Sample/Shared/ValueObjects/Password.php:15

which looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace SmoothCode\Sample\Shared\ValueObjects;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class Password {
    protected string $hash;

    public function __construct($plainPassword)
    {
        Assert::minLength($plainPassword, 6);

        $this->hash = Hash::make($plainPassword);
    }

    public function hashedPassword()
    {
        return $this->hash;
    }


}
```

```
I was trying to run:
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

But I'm still getting this error.

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: Where should I use this? In my Test Case?

Comment: Mehran Zamani, for clarity, class `SmoothCode\Sample\Domain\User\User` is not Model class and it is not operating on database

Comment: which line is UserDomainTest.php:29 ? You should explain more details about your code. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456595/laravel-5-8-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set-after-homestead-restart).

Comment: UserDomainTest.php:29 is this line:

```
            ConfirmationCode::generate()
```

But what i've discoverd is that even when i replace whole code in `testUserCreation()` with :
```
Hash::make('test');
```
or
```
bcrypt('test');
```

I'm getting this error. So calling Facade in my tests is causing this error.

Comment: please provide ConfirmationCode in your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution for this error. For anyone who would have same problem:

My UserDomainTest was extending TestCase from namespace:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

when I've changed to:

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
```

everything works like a charm.

Comment: How come the examples in the official docs extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and not `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`?

Comment: can not change into  `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;`  because is not implement `createApplication` method

Comment: Both of these are wrong; you need to extend `Tests\TestCase` as shown in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database-testing) for database testing.

Comment: This forces you to implement a function called `createApplication`, which is out of scope for this solution. @caio-denadai their solution is the correct answer IMO.

Answer (score 8):

The Jakub's answer don't work for me, so I will explain what I do.

I have the file App/BusinessRules/Admin/Tests/EnvTest.php.
Even using anyone of this 2 namespaces the fail occurs.

So in my EnvTest I extend the tests/TestCase.php file from the namespace:

```
use Tests\TestsCase
```

Comment: If you define your own `protected function setUp(): void` then don't forget to call `parent::setUp();` too or you'll still get the same error about `A facade root has not been set`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `parent::setUp();` at the top of the protected function fixed the error for me.