# Facing facades issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, facade, laravel-facade

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /app/dragonglass/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /app/dragonglass/crm/app/helpers.php(617): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('Header', Array) #1 /app/dragonglass/crm/app/helpers.php(556): getLoggerBasicData('Call to undefin...', '') #2 /app/dragonglass/crm/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(40): logError('Call to undefin...', '', Array) #3 /app/dragonglass/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError)) #4 /app/dragonglass/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError)) #5 /app/dragonglass/crm/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #6 {main} thrown in /app/dragonglass/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 218
```

Facing the above issue in Laravel 5.6 any solution please?

Comment: Is the answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818102/laravel-5-6-uncaught-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set?

Comment: @SokChanty  Where that container need to make?
as said like
You need to create a new app container and then bind it to the Facade.